# What is the architecture behind Golang's Go Routine?

Tags: go, concurrency

What is the architecture behind Golang's Go Routine?

I believe that Go doesn't just fork a new thread for each routine.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/222642/are-go-langs-goroutine-pools-just-green-threads ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058164/is-golang-goroutine-a-coroutine - more insteresting reading, search for 'green threads', as the term commonly fits in the talk

Comment: Without an extra careful reading of the spec: I think this is an implementation "detail".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been Go implementations in the past that did in fact create a new thread for each goroutine.

In the main Go implementation, a Go routine is basically just a stack (usually small) with some additional context (in 1.5, see `type g` in runtime/runtime2.go).  Changing from goroutine to another means changing the stack pointer and the thread-local variable that points to the currently running goroutine.