# goroutines affect each other when printing timecost

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm a freshman for Golang. I know goroutine is an abstract group of cpu and memory to run a piece of code.

So When I run some computing funcs(like sort) in goroutines, I'm hoping they run parallel. But the printed result seems weird, the "paralell" codes print nearly the same timecost.

Why? Is there something I missed about goroutine, or it's because of the func printTime() ?

codes: https://play.golang.org/p/n9DLn57ftM

P.S. codes should be copied to local go file and run. Those run in play.golang has some limitation.

the result is:

```
MaxProcs: 8

Source : 2.0001ms
Quick sort : 3.0002ms
Merge sort : 8.0004ms
Insertion sort : 929.0532ms
Goroutine num: 1

Source : 2.0001ms
Goroutine num: 4

Insertion sort : 927.0531ms
Quick sort : 930.0532ms
Merge sort : 934.0535ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should measure **total time cost** instead of *individual time cost* required by each sorting algorithm. The individual time cost might be longer when the task is distributed into several `goroutines` since it need additional time to setup the `goroutine`.  Depending on the nature of your program, additional time might be needed for communication between `goroutine` and/or with *main process*. There're some resources related to `goroutine`, e.g.

1. [Is a Go goroutine a coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058164/is-a-go-goroutine-a-coroutine)
2. http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/

If you change `main` function to:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("MaxProcs:", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)) // 8

    start := time.Now()
    sequentialTest()
    seq := time.Now()
    concurrentTest()
    con := time.Now()

    fmt.Printf("\n\nCalculation time, sequential: %v, concurrent: %v\n",
        seq.Sub(start), con.Sub(seq))
}
```

the output will look like:

```
MaxProcs: 4

Source : 3.0037ms
Quick sort : 5.0034ms
Merge sort : 13.0069ms
Insertion sort : 1.2590941s
Goroutine num: 1

Source : 3.0015ms
Goroutine num: 4

Insertion sort : 1.2399076s
Quick sort : 1.2459121s
Merge sort : 1.2519156s

Calculation time, sequential: 1.2831112s, concurrent: 1.2559194s
```

After removing `printTime`, it looks like:

```
MaxProcs: 4
Goroutine num: 1
Goroutine num: 4

Calculation time, sequential: 1.3154314s, concurrent: 1.244112s
```

The time cost value might change slightly, but most of the time the result will be `sequential > concurrent`. In summary, distributing the task into several `goroutines`, may increase the overall performance (*time cost*) but not the individual task.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand what you want to test. At the first, you code doesn't work for quickSort because you run quickSort with `go quickSort(...)`.

```
wg.Add(1)
go func(){
    go quickSort(s1, nil)
    wg.Done()
}()
```

This goroutine will quit immediately.
Now, I tested your code. And I notice that you must get total time between start and all of finish.

https://play.golang.org/p/O8Gj-OYIdR

Answer (score 0):

```
wg.Add(1)
go func(){
    go quickSort(s1, nil)
    wg.Done()
}()
```

You don't need that second `go`

It should be like

```
wg.Add(1)
go func(){
    quickSort(s1, nil)
    wg.Done()
}()
```

What happened is that go func() started one goroutine, and `go quickSort(s1, nil)` starts another. As a result, wg.Done() (and, as a result, wg.Done()) gets executed practically right away (without waiting for quickSort).