# Python asyncio event loop equivalent in Go lang

Tags: python, go, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

I use `asyncio` event loop which is a kind of performing asynchronous/concurrency tasks in *Python3.x* .

Is there any equivalent of `asyncio` (async/await) or coroutines in Go lang on **a thread** only?

---

[**NOTE**]:

Not `parallelism + concurrency` (multiprocessing) pattern.

---

[UPDATE]:

Here is an asynchronous event loop using `asyncio` in Python for better sense:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def async_say(delay, msg):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(msg)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_say(4, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_say(6, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Out:

```
started at 13:19:44
hello
world
finished at 13:19:50
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking third-party resources such as libraries, are off-topic. Rather than asking for an equivalent to a language primitive, a better approach is to ask a question about a specific problem you're actually facing in Go, and how to address it.

Comment: Just ask what you need specifically. Your question is not just clear.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma I updated my question for better sense, I looking for an equivalent method/pattern in Go lang

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python terms, the event loop is **built into** Go. You would launch two goroutines with `go async_say(...)` and wait for them to complete, for example using a [channel](https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization) or a [wait group](https://medium.com/@matryer/very-basic-concurrency-for-beginners-in-go-663e63c6ba07).

A straightforward translation of your code to Go could look like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func async_say(delay time.Duration, msg string, done chan bool) {
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Println(msg)
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    done1 := make(chan bool, 1)
    go async_say(4 * time.Second, "hello", done1)
    done2 := make(chan bool, 1)
    go async_say(6 * time.Second, "world", done2)
    <-done1
    <-done2
}
```

Note that, unlike Python (and JavaScript, etc.), Go functions do not come in different [colors](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) depending on whether they are asynchronous or not. They can *all* be run asynchronously, and the equivalent of asyncio is built into the standard library.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you write the equivalent of example in question in Go? and what is the difference between thread, process, and coroutines in Go and how to access them?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari I've added a roughly equivalent example. *what is the difference between thread, process, and coroutines in Go and how to access them?* Those questions are way out of scope for a StackOverflow answer; you might want to consult a book on Go.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need this in Go as in Go this would be an anti-pattern.

Instead, in Go, you have management of ["pollable" descriptors](https://manpages.debian.org/2/poll) — such as sockets — tightly integrated with the runtime and the goroutine scheduler.
This allows you to write normal *sequential* code which will internally be handled via a platform-specific "eventful" interface (such as `epoll` on Linux, `kqueue` on FreeBSD and IOCP on Windows).
As soon as a goroutine tries to perform any I/O on a socket and the socket is not ready, the goroutine gets suspended until that data is ready after which it will be resumed right at the place it has been suspended.

Hence in Go, you merely create a separate goroutine to serve each request which should be performed or served concurrently with the others and write plain sequential code to handle it.

For backrgound, start [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/go-hits-the-concurrency-nail-right-on-the-head/) and [here](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/).

The tutorials explaining how the Go scheduler works are,
for instance, [this](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/)
and [this](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler).

Comment: Thanks for useful links and goroutines keyword like the `coroutines`.

Comment: I failed to parse that passage regarding corouties and the goroutines. Judging from your other comment, you might be confusing these two terms but [they are profoundly different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18061564/720999). As the other person who answered your question suggested, you seem to lack even the most basic knowledge of Go. The "problem" with Go is that its approach to concurrency is vastly different from most other mainstream languages (maybe except Erlang) so you simply cannot sufficiently reason about it w/o gaining some basic familiarity with the language.

Comment: Start with [the tour](https://tour.golang.org) and then proceed to [books](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Books). If you're seriously determined learning Go, I'd recommend to jump straight to [GOPL](http://www.gopl.io/), otherwise start with something free, like [this one](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro).

Comment: Thanks again. I thought that coroutine and goroutine are similar, So I've been the mistake.

Comment: A fun thing is that Russ Cox has recently posted an essay on [how coroutines could be fitted in Go](https://research.swtch.com/coro), and why this could be useful. I have a feeling coroutines will eventually become a part of the Go's standard library ;-)